# Firebase Messaging on Flutter after update

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been using Firebase Messaging in my app for a couple of years but after I decided to update my app and updated Flutter and plugin versions my existing code stopped working. I checked the official documentations but couldn't find an answer to why this code is not working. The code I use is below. What has changed in the new version causing my code to cease working?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      setState(() {
        _homeScreenText = "Push Messaging token: $token";
      });
      print(_homeScreenText);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the old method. Here is the new method:

My firebase_messaging package version is 10.0.1.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      showNotification(notification);
});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("onMessageOpenedApp: $message");
});

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("onBackgroundMessage: $message");
});
```